# Android: Notification builder: alternative to setcolor method for API19

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to set the color of notification. It works fine if minSdk is at least `API Level 21`. Once I drop the minSdk, code (below) doesn't compile.

```
notification = builder.setContentTitle(MyApp.getAppContext().getResources().getString(R.string.notification_content_title))
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setColor(color)
                .build();
```

I get the following error message once I downgrade MinSdk to `API Level 19`:

> Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19): android.app.Notification.Builder#setColor

What would be the workaround? I came across NotificationCompact, should I switch to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [`NotificationCompat.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) (from support library) instead of [`Notification.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html).

To do so you will need the support v4 library in your project. If you don't have it already add this line to the dependencies closure of your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1"
```

Then you would use `NotificationCompat.Builder` to make your notification.

```
String title = MyApp.getAppContext().getResources()
                                   .getString(R.string.notification_content_title);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                 .setContentTitle(title)
                 .setContentText(contentText)
                 .setColor(color)
                 .build();
```

Note that `NotificationCompat.Builder` cannot not backport all the functionality into older versions of android. Most of it (like the color of the notification) will be ignored in older versions of android. `NotificationCompat.Builder` will just prevent the errors you are seeing.

Alternatively you could add a SDK check before setting the color, but that would be a more verbose approach to doing what `NotificationCompat.Builder` does for you:

```
String title = MyApp.getAppContext().getResources().getString(R.string.notification_content_title);
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
                 .setContentTitle(title)
                 .setContentText(contentText);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= ApiHelper.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  builder.setColor(color);
}
Notification notification = builder.build();
```

Comment: I am using V7 Library now (and cant replace it). Adding V4 library increases apk size. Any other alternatives

Comment: Yea, you could do an SDK check before calling the method setColor. Ill add sample code. In general I would recommend using both v4 and v7.

Comment: @kashili as far as I know, importing v7 will automatically allow you to use v4's components.

Comment: Sufian is right, [NotificationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) can also be used from v7. My bad!

Comment: @kashili btw v4 and v7 are not competitors. v4 means that it is available for API 4 and up, while v7 means that this particular library is available for API 7 and up. What you're doing currently is using `android.app.Notification`, what Dr. Nitpick is saying is that you replace it with `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`, which is not much of an ask.

Comment: @Dr.Nitpick prefer to avoid using `+` in gradle imports. The disadvantages are that the builds can become unpredictable (which AS already tells you) and you will need a working internet connection for generating an APK (I faced it once) and also builds become slow (since it checks for latest version).

Comment: @Dr.Nitpick: I replaced my code with your code (and changed gradle file). I donot see any change in notification color on nexus 5 (4.4) and Huewi(5.0.1). Any guess why it doesnt work. It does set the color of notification on the 3rd phone (nexus 5 with 6.0.1).

Comment: @kashili probably because it is not backported. But now you don't have to put if-else to see if the method exists or not, as the NotificationCompat does it for you.

Comment: Exactly. As I said in the answer this functionality can't be back ported as the older os's don't support it.